# How do I fix (or remap) the keys in the inventory screen?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I recently upgraded my 10 year old video adapter, and decided to have a go at Skyrim again - this time the Special Edition. All was nice until I noticed a problem - I like to remap a few of the keys because... I'm just used to that. For example, I use <kbd>F</kbd> for holstering/unholstering weapons; and I use <kbd>E</kbd> for shouting.

The problem is in the inventory/loot screen - not only does it use some totally unrelated keys, the on-screen keyboard hints don't even reflect the proper keys.

For example, the key to favorite items is the same as the one for "Toggle First/Third person view". It defaults to <kbd>F</kbd>, but I've remapped it to <kbd>T</kbd>. However, the inventory screen still shows <kbd>F</kbd> as the shortcut for favoriting things - even though I actually need to press <kbd>T</kbd> instead, and pressing <kbd>F</kbd> drops the item.

This is annoying as hell. The best thing would be if I could use a separate keymapping for the inventory screen, because I'm used to the defaults being used there, however, I'd also settle for it simply showing the right keys - at least it would remind me what to press.

Unfortunately I haven't been able to find a mod that would to that. I don't know if I simply haven't tried the right keywords in Google, or if such a mod is impossible. Does anyone know anything about this?

I know I'm not the first one with this problem - forum topics about it are plenty, but none of them actually offer a fix - just explain the problem to confused players who find themselves unable to work with their inventories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Keyboard Remap Fix](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/5245/)?

Alternatively, you might want to look into this mod: [Interface Hard Coded Key Tweaks](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/88/). This one seems especially appropriate in your situation.

Even though these mods are created for the old Skyrim, they might work fine for the Special Edition.

Comment: Nice find, I'll try them tomorrow (going to bed now).

Comment: @Vilx Any luck using these?

Comment: Sorry, didn't try them yesterday after all. But I did now - the Keyboard Remap Fix worked like a charm, perfect! Just what I wanted. I didn't even check out the other mod. :)

Comment: Ermm... ok... now I'm feeling stoopid. I went to put the mod away in my "useful mods and updates" folder and there, staring right back at me, was something called "On-screen Interface Key Fix v105-368". By the looks of the contents, it does the exact same thing as the "Keyboard Remap Fix". Ergh... Well, at least maybe this question will help someone else in the future. :)

Comment: The irony of having everything neatly organized and still turning to the internet, I guess? Happens to me all the time. Glad it worked out for you all the same.